# Can you Define $home as 'C:/user/%username%/' property for an installer

Tags: windows, properties, installation, directory

I've been looking through [Property References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905%28VS.85%29.aspx) and I cannot find anything that relates directly to 'C:/user/%username%/' or $home so I can install files to a folder generally in the "downloads" folder. Simplar to [AppDataFolder] but not to the roaming folder.

Comment: Why would you want to install files to the "downloads" dir?

Comment: Most of the people who use a this program it installs files into the folder that it is in and I wanted to allow files to be added to the program without moving their folder

Answer (score 0):

You will not find a predefined property for that folder, you need to create the path at install time. The following article explains how you can do it with [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com), I don't know what tool you are using but maybe you can get the same done with it too.
http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-custom-folder.html

Also, this should be possible to achieve with the free edition of Advanced Installer too, i.e. "Simple" project type.